Silence unknown callers on Macbook
I have silence unknown callers on in my iPhone. The unknown calls don't go through my iPhone anymore but still ring on my Mac. Is there a way to silence unknown callers on my Macbook?

What versions of iOS and MacOS are you running on your devices?

iOS 17.4.1, MacOS Sonoma 14.4 @music2myear
